# Extension field with roots of unity(Basis and generator of the field As the vector space)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, galois-theory

Put the $K$ is a finite extension field over the  field $F$.

If so, $[K;F]$ = (The number of the basis  of the K over F )

e.x.) $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) ; \mathbb{Q} ] = 3 $ (Since the basis are $\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{4} ,\sqrt[3]{8}$ )

As a vector space, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) = \langle \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{4} ,\sqrt[3]{8}\rangle$

So Here is the my question begins.

Say $f(x) = x^n -1$ and $g(x) = x^{2n}-1$(or $x^n +1)$ with each roots $\alpha = e^{{2\pi i}  \over {n}}$ and $\beta = e^{{2\pi i}  \over 2n }$ respectively.

Let the $K_1=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $K_2=\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ be a splitting field of $f$ and $g$ over  the $\mathbb{Q}$ respectively.

Then $[K_1 ; \mathbb{Q} ] = \phi (n)$ and $[K_2 ; \mathbb{Q} ] = \phi (2n)$

And it is clear that $K_1 = \langle 1, \alpha, \alpha^{2}, ...  \alpha^{n-1}\rangle$ and $K_2 = \langle 1, \beta, \beta^{2}, ...  \beta^{n-1}\rangle$

(When the $\beta$ case, because of the $\beta^n = -1, \beta^{n+1} = -\beta, ..., \beta^{2n} = 1$)

**First question**, Does two equations (1) and (2) hold?

(1) $K_1 = \langle \alpha ^{i} \vert (i,n)=1$ or $i =n\rangle $ = $\langle 1, \alpha, \alpha^{2}, ...  \alpha^{n-1}\rangle$

(2) $K_2 = \langle \beta^{i} \vert (i,2n) =1$ or $i =2n \rangle$ =  $\langle 1, \beta, \beta^{2}, ...  \beta^{n-1}\rangle$

In my thought, considering the case $n=8$, $\alpha^2 \not \in  \ \langle \alpha ^{i} \vert (i,8)=1$ or $i =8\rangle$ for $\alpha^2(\in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha))$

Hence, $\{\alpha ^{i} \vert (i,n)=1$ or $i =n\}$ **is not** a basis(generator) of the $Q(\alpha)$.

I'm very confused 'cause it looks like a basis on the fact that $[K_1 ; \mathbb{Q}] = \phi(n)$

**Sencond question**, Then What is generator(or basis) of the $Q(\alpha)$ and $Q(\beta)$?

It is clear that generator of the $K_1$ and $K_2$ are $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^{2}, ...  \alpha^{n-1} \}$ and $\{1, \beta, \beta^{2}, ...  \beta^{n-1} \}$ respectively.

If the equations in first question don't hold, What is the basis $Q(\alpha)$ and $Q(\beta)$??

Comment: In fact, (1) and (2) are wrong. Take $n=8$ then you can see that the set $K_1$ is not linearly independent (as $\alpha+\alpha^5=0$.)

Comment: Hmm... then $\{\alpha^{i} \vert (i,n)=1\} $is not the basis of the $K_1$. But Is it true the number of the $K_1$- basis over$ \mathbb{Q}$ is$ \phi(n) $?

Comment: I have no idea, but I think [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) are closely related to your question, as your extensions (called cyclotomic extension) are splitting fields of that polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bases should be $K_1 = \langle 1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \dots, \alpha^{\phi(n) -1} \rangle$ and $K_2 = \langle 1, \beta, \beta^2, \dots, \beta^{\phi(2n) - 1} \rangle$.

As for why $[\mathbf{Q}(e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{n}}) : \mathbf{Q}] = \phi(n)$, even though $\alpha = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{n}}$ is a root of $x^n - 1$, the latter isn't irreducible over $\mathbf{Q}$. Instead, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $$p(x) = \prod_{1 \leq i < n\\(i,n) = 1} \big ( x - \alpha^i \big ),$$

which clearly has degree $\phi(n)$.

You should be able to find a reference for this in pretty much any algebra book.